# casting object using name

Tags: c#, casting, object-type

I need to cast different objects to different types using the literal string name. Some example code:

```
string controlName = "Control";
string stringName = "string";
string panelName = "Panel";

var x = Panel();

((Control)x).Name = "SomeName";
```

The above code works of course, but instead of this line

```
 ((Control)x).Name = "Normal";
```

How do I use the line

```
((controlName)x).Name = "Awesome";
```

I hope this makes sense, but if I need to explain further I can try.

I am creating a series of questions defined in an xml schema. The Question will vary such as 
1. What time did this happen.
2 Why did this happen.
3. What type was this(type 1,type 2, type3)

All of these are read by one base control. 1 needs the answer control to be a date time picker, two needs a textbox, 3 needs a combobox.

I would subscribe to the textchange event of the textbox, the value changed event of the datetimepicker, and the selectedindexchange event of the combobox.

This is oversimplifying it, what I am actually doing is with controls and created events.

The way I am handling it now, is a gigantic case statement. I wondered if there was an easier way to do with with conversion of the control to the type defined in the xml document(string value)

EDIT*

Code as was asked for

```
namespace ScriptControl
{
 public partial class ScriptItem
 {
    public FollowupEvent ActiveEvent{get;set;}

    public event EventHandler AnswerChanged;

    #region Constructors

    public ScriptItem()
    {
    }

    public ScriptItem(DataRow row)
    {
    }

    public ScriptItem(XElement xelem,FollowupEvent activeEvent,int instanceID)
    {
        ActiveEvent = activeEvent;

        InstanceID = instanceID;

        try
        {
            Question = xelem.Elements("Text").First().Value.ToString();
            AnswerType = xelem.Elements("Type").First().Value.ToString();
            ControlType = xelem.Elements("Control").First().Attribute("Type").Value.ToString();
            ActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString());
            ScriptItemType = xelem.Elements("ScriptItemType").First().Value.ToString();
            ScriptItemQuestionType = xelem.Elements("QuestionType").First().Value.ToString();
            InputControl = ConfigureInputControl(xelem.Elements("Control").First().Attribute("Type").Value.ToString());
            QuestionControl = ConfigureQuestionControl(xelem.Elements("Control").First().Attribute("Type").Value.ToString());
            Prompt = xelem.Elements("Prompt").First().Value.ToString();
        }
        catch { }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public string Prompt { get; set; }

    public Panel QuestionPanel = new Panel();

    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string AnswerType { get; set; }

    public object Result { get; set; }

    public Control InputControl { get; set; }

    public string ControlType { get; set; }

    public Control QuestionControl { get; set; }

    public string ScriptItemType { get; set; }

    public string ScriptItemQuestionType { get; set; }

    public int InstanceID { get; set; }

    public ScriptControl.Entities.ScriptControlBase ScriptBaseControl { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public Control ConfigureInputControl(string controlType)
    {
        switch (controlType)
                {
                    case "Checkbox":
                    InputControl = new CheckBox();
                    break;

                    case "BooleanQuestion":
                    InputControl = new BooleanQuestion();
                    ((BooleanQuestion)InputControl).AnswerChanged += ScriptItem_AnswerChanged;
                    ((BooleanQuestion)InputControl).SetQuestion(Question);
                    break;

                    case "TextBox":
                    InputControl = new TextBox();
                    ((TextBox)InputControl).KeyDown += ScriptItem_AnswerChanged;
                    break;

                    case "RadioButton":
                    InputControl = new RadioButton();
                    break;

                    case "DropDown":
                    InputControl = new RadioButton();
                    break;

                    case "DateTimePicker":
                    InputControl = new DateTimePicker();
                    ((DateTimePicker)InputControl).KeyDown += ScriptItem_AnswerChanged;
                    break;

                   case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.CauseForRepair":
                   case".CustomControls.SmartParts.Airlines":
                   case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.DREntry":
                        InputControl = GetUIControl();
                        ((FN_ControlBase)InputControl).PropertyChanged += ScriptItem_AnswerChanged;
                       break;
    }
        return InputControl;
    }

    private void ScriptItem_AnswerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> workFlowParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        switch (ControlType)
        {
            case "BooleanQuestion":
                Control x = ((Control)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent;

                Result = ((BooleanQuestion)x).Answer;

                workFlowParams.Add("QuestionID",Activity);
                workFlowParams.Add("InstanceID", InstanceID);
                workFlowParams.Add("Result",Result);
            break;

            case "TextBox":
                if (((KeyEventArgs)e).KeyValue == 13)
                {
                    Result = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

                    workFlowParams.Add("QuestionID", Activity);
                    workFlowParams.Add("InstanceID", InstanceID);
                    workFlowParams.Add("Result", Result);
                }
                break;

            case "DateTimePicker":
                if (((KeyEventArgs)e).KeyValue == 13)
                {
                    Result = ((DateTimePicker)sender).Text;

                    workFlowParams.Add("QuestionID", Activity);
                    workFlowParams.Add("InstanceID", InstanceID);
                    workFlowParams.Add("Result", Result);
                }
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Airlines":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.CauseForRepairUI":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.CancelCallUI":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.CostCenter":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.ReadyToBill":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.TemporaryFix":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.BrakeRepairFollowup":
            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.DREntry":
            default:
                if (((PropertyChangedEventArgs)e).PropertyName == "WorkComplete" & Convert.ToBoolean(((.CustomControls.FN_ControlBase)sender).GetPropertyValue("WorkComplete")) == true)
                {
                    foreach (var propty in ((.CustomControls.FN_ControlBase)sender).GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (ActiveEvent.HasProperty(propty.Name) & propty.Name != "EventID")
                        {
                            ActiveEvent.SetPropertyValue(propty.Name, ((Control)sender).GetPropertyValue(propty.Name));
                        }
                    }
                }

                workFlowParams.Add("QuestionID", Activity);
                workFlowParams.Add("InstanceID", InstanceID);
                workFlowParams.Add("Result", ActiveEvent);
                break;
        }

        AnswerChanged(workFlowParams, e);
    }

    public Control ConfigureQuestionControl(string controlType)
    {
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case "BooleanQuestion":
                ((BooleanQuestion)InputControl).SetQuestion(Question);
                break;

            case "TextBox":
                QuestionControl = new Label { Visible = true, Location = new Point(0, 0), Text = Question};
                break;

            case "DateTimePicker":
                QuestionControl = new Label { Visible = true, Location = new Point(0, 0), Text = Question};
                break;
        }

        return QuestionControl;
    }

    public Control ConfigureControl()
    {
        var height = 0;
        var width = 0;

        ScriptBaseControl = new ScriptControl.Entities.ScriptControlBase();

        if (InputControl is BooleanQuestion || ScriptItemType == "Control")
        {
            InputControl = ConfigureInputControl(ControlType);

            ScriptBaseControl.AddControl(InputControl);

            ScriptBaseControl.SetPrompt(Prompt);

            foreach (Control c in ScriptBaseControl.FilterControls(ctl => !(ctl is Panel) && !(ctl is FlowLayoutPanel) && !(ctl is GroupBox) && !(ctl is ScriptControlBase)))
            {
                height = height + c.Height;
                if (c.Width > width)
                {
                    width = c.Width;
                }
            }

            ScriptBaseControl.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }
        else
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel x = new FlowLayoutPanel();

            x.Controls.Add(QuestionControl);

            x.Controls.Add(InputControl);

            foreach (Control c in ScriptBaseControl.FilterControls(ctl => !(ctl is Panel) && !(ctl is FlowLayoutPanel) && !(ctl is GroupBox) && !(ctl is ScriptControlBase)))
            {
                height = height + c.Height;
                if (c.Width > width)
                {
                    width = c.Width;
                }
            }

            x.Size = new Size(width, height);

            ScriptBaseControl.Size = x.Size;

            ScriptBaseControl.AddControl(x);

            ScriptBaseControl.SetPrompt(Prompt);
        }
        return ScriptBaseControl;
    }

    private Control GetUIControl()
    { 
        Control uiControl = new Control(); 

        switch (ControlType)
          {
              case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Air":
                  uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.Airlines(ActiveEvent.EventID) { ExternalSave = true};
               break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.CauseFor":
               uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.CauseForRepairUI() { ExternalSave = true };
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Cancel":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.CancelCallUI() { ExternalSave = true,EventID = ActiveEvent.EventID };
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Cost":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.CostCenter() { ExternalSave = true};
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.ReadyTo":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.ReadyToBill(ActiveEvent.EventID) { ExternalSave = true, EventID = ActiveEvent.EventID };
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Temporary":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.TemporaryFix() { ExternalSave = true};
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.RepairFollowup":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.BrakeRepairFollowup() { ExternalSave = true, EventID = ActiveEvent.EventID};
                break;

            case ".CustomControls.SmartParts.Entry":
                uiControl = new .CustomControls.SmartParts.DREntry() { ExternalSave = true };
                break;
        }

        return uiControl;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to cast a variable to a class whose name is dynamically set in another string variable? Why do you need that? There might be a much simpler way to achieve what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: no you can't do that.

Comment: Note that all you can get from that string is a `Type` object, and you can't cast from that as discussed in the duplicate.

Comment: ...and you dont need the casting as the types are infered.

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't called casting. You are trying to access the `Property` called `Name` on the class `ControlName`. This is called `Reflection`, and its an utter pain it the $%&*. Alternatively you could use `duck-typing`, which can be done by casting to the type `dynamic`. However this does not help if the object implements multiple `Name` Properties.

Comment: However it is exceedingly rare that you want to do that. In 99.9999% of cases, there should be a base class that implements the property you want.

Comment: perhaps you may be wanting to use an `enum` better yet make a switch{} case and check on the Control name other than that what you are trying to do can't be done.. unless you are checking the Control type meaning if Control is TextBox for example etc.. then check for Sender name etc

Comment: sounds like you need a common base class or interface for all those controls

Comment: @WellEveryone. I will try to address all of these comments in the main question with edits.

Comment: @aron actually, its not what I am trying to do. I am trying to subscribe to an event of the Control. so the example is meant to show my intent and clarify what i mean by casting with a string value. I dont really need to access the Name property, or any property.

Comment: I didn't understand a word you wrote in your Question. Please could you rephrase your question in C# (post your (cutdown) existing code, since there is no ambiguity in that).

Comment: it will involve some code but couldn't this be acheived with reflection? and maybe a helpclass or 2

Comment: Im thinking most likely reflection, but back to my original question of...how?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this because `C#` is a *statically typed* language. The type you want to cast should be known at compile time so the compiler can tread `x` as `Control` (or whatever) in the rest of the code.If you could do this:

```
((controlName)x).Name = "Awesome";
```

There is no way to know what is the value of `controlName` or is it a valid type name until runtime.So the type of `x` can not be determined at compile time which violates the type-safety.

The only exception to static typing in `C#` is `dynamic` feature which allows you to declare a variable as `dynamic` and bypass the compile time checks.You can do any operation and access any member of a `dynamic` variable at compile time without getting any error.But if you access a member that don't exists you will get a `RuntimeBinderException` at runtime.

This can be useful in some cases, for example you can create a method that takes `string` type name as parameter, get the type using `Type.GetType` method and use `Convert.ChangeType` method to change type of your object, and assign the result to a `dynamic` variable. That way you can perform any operation on your *dynamic* object but you should be careful.BTW,even though this is possible, it is not a preferable way.

Comment: Ahem...C#3 is a statically typed language. C#4 onwards maybe used as a duck-typed language.

Comment: I rarely see the word can't when talking of c#

Comment: @CalvinSmith There are plenty of things you *cant* do in C#. There is a workaround (using `dynamic`) in this case; but the provided syntax will never be valid.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I never meant to ask if the above syntax is valid. It obviously is not. I was clarifying my intentions with an example of how it would look if it was possible.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I read your edit but still do not understand what are you trying to accomplish. maybe you should show us your _gigantic case statement_ so we can at least have  an idea about what is your intent